# Android gallery:Bitmap Images throws arrayIndexOutOfBoundException

Tags: android, bitmap, gallery

Below is my code:

```
String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[] {ImageColumns._ID}, null, null,null);
if ((cur != null) && cur.moveToFirst()) {
    //  Integer idsArray[] = new Integer[cur.getCount()];
    for (int i = 0; i < cur.getCount(); i++) {
        idsArray[i] = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(ImageColumns._ID));


        cur.moveToNext();
    }

}
Bitmap originalImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0])));
int width = originalImage.getWidth();

int height = originalImage.getHeight();

cur.close();
```

I want to get height and width of each images. I want to use `getHeight()` and `getWidth()` method, but code above is giving me an error. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this

```
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, **new String[] {ImageColumns._ID}**, null, null,null);
```

You are querying only `ImageColumns._ID` field. Add `MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA` and it will be ok.

Like this:

```
    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[] { ImageColumns._ID, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA }, null, null, null);

    if ((cur != null) && cur.moveToFirst()) {
        //  Integer idsArray[] = new Integer[cur.getCount()];
        for (int i = 0; i < cur.getCount(); i++) {
            cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(ImageColumns._ID));

            Bitmap originalImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0])));
            int width = originalImage.getWidth();
            int height = originalImage.getHeight();

            cur.moveToNext();
        }

    }

    cur.close();
```

Comment: its showing me android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundException:Index 2 requested,with a size of 2.

Comment: yes I changed the code as suggested by you but it still throwing error.

Comment: You are trying to read cursor after it is positioned after last element. Try to move width and height read code inside for loop.

Comment: If I want to fetch images from SD Card then where should I need to change in above code.As I need id of each images as mentioned in the above code.Please help me out

Comment: This code is indeed fetches images from SD card. Why isn't this enough to you?